# Local integrability of $1/u$ implies $u>0$ almost everywhere

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}$ be open.  For a positive $\mathcal{B}(U)$-measurable function $u$, we define

\begin{eqnarray*}
S_{u}:=\left\{ x \in U:  \int_{ \overline{B_{\epsilon}(x)}} u^{-1}(t)dt < \infty \,\,{\rm for\,some }\,\, \epsilon>0  \right\}
\end{eqnarray*}

where $\overline{B_{\epsilon}(x)}=\{y \in {U}:|y-x|\leq\epsilon\}$.

I want to show that $S_{u}$ is open and that $u>0\, \mu-a.e.$ on $S_{u}$ ($\mu$ is Lebesgue measure on $U$ )

The former is easy. In fact, let $x \in S_{u}$ then $B_{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}(x) \subset S_{u}$.

The latter: Since for any $x \in S_{u}$, $\int_{ \overline{B_{\epsilon}(x)}} u^{-1}(t)dt < \infty$ then

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mu \left(t \in \overline{B_{\epsilon}(x)}: u(t)=0  \right)=0
\end{eqnarray*}

This implies $u(t)>0\,\mu-a.e. {\rm on}\,B_{\epsilon}(x) $. But my purpose is to prove

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mu \left(t \in S_{u}: u(t)=0  \right)=0\tag1
\end{eqnarray*}

How do I get to $(1)$? Thanks.

Comment: First, I'd suggest you to use the notation $\frac{1}{u(x)}$ instead of $u^{-1}$, which might be confusing.

Here is my (unfinished) proposition : let $\tilde{S}_{u} = \mathbb{Q}\cap S_{u}$, which is denumerable. For every $x \in \tilde{S}_{u}$, there exists $\epsilon >0$ such that $\bar{B}(x,\epsilon) \subset S_{u}$. If you succeed in proving that $\mu(S_{u} \setminus \cup_{x \in \tilde{S}_{u}}\bar{B}(x, \epsilon) ) =0$, then you could write : $$\mu(t : u(t) = 0) \leq \sum_{x\in \tilde{S}_{u}} \mu(t : t\in \bar{B}(x, \epsilon), u(t) =0) = 0$$ which would be what you're asking for.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! You've been very helpful.

Comment: To number equations, use `$$ ..... \tag1 $$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach, not necessarily shortest but it works. Write $U$ as a countable union of compact sets $K_n$, for example $K_n$ could consist of all points $x$ such that $|x|\le n$ and $\operatorname{dist}(x,\partial U)\ge 1/n$. This is   called *exhaustion by compact subsets*.

Cover $K_n$  by  balls of the form $B_\epsilon$ on which you know $u>0$ a.e. Take a finite subcover. Conclude $u>0$ a.e. on $K_n$. Take union over $n$.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know exhaustion by compact subsets. I was very surprised.